# Angular Dynamic Reactive Form Nested - FormArray Approach for CheckBoxes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am stuck with a logical issue here about using Reactive Forms in Angular.

I have an object similar to the one below.

```
interface MenuGroup {
  title: string;
  menuItems: MenuItem[];
};

interface MenuItem {
  title: string;
  status: string;
};

interface RoleModel {
  roleName: string;
  menuGroup: MenuGroup[];
};

role: RoleModel
```

Menu Item is basically a check box in the UI.

List of Menu Items belonging to its Menu Group will be displayed under its title.

Like,

Menu Group Name
1. Menu Item 1 --> CheckBox
2. Menu Item 2 --> CheckBox

So, now the question..

I need to build a Reactive Form for this problem. 
I am not able to come up with a solution. I am trying to build nested FormArrays but in vain.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've created a example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-test). But it's not complete.

Comment: That's a lot of effort. Thank you! But can you explain a bit? Or may be provide links to the resource? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggest. I assume that your `role` varible is equal to something like this object.

```
this.role = {
      roleName: 'Test Role name',
      menuGroup: [
        {
          title: 'menu group 1',
          menuItems: [
            {
              title: 'group 1 item 1',
              status: 'active'
            },
            {
              title: 'group 1 item 2',
              status: 'inactive'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: 'menu group 2',
          menuItems: [
            {
              title: 'group 2 item 1',
              status: 'active'
            },
            {
              title: 'group 2 item 2',
              status: 'inactive'
            },
            {
              title: 'group 2 item 3',
              status: 'active'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
```

What you have to do is create formgroups for each of the `menuItems` and add them to `FormArray`. Then you have to create `FormGroup`s for each of the `menuGroup` and add them to a single `FormArray`. At the end if you get the value of the whole form group ist should look like this.

```
{
  "title": "Test Role name",
  "menuGroups": [
    {
      "title": "menu group 1",
      "items": [
        {
          "group 1 item 1": null,
          "group 1 item 2": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "menu group 2",
      "items": [
        {
          "group 2 item 1": null,
          "group 2 item 2": null,
          "group 2 item 3": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Create three methods like this.

```
private buildForm(): void {
    const formArray = this.fb.array([]);
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      title: [this.role.roleName],
      menuGroups: formArray
    });
    this.role.menuGroup.forEach((menuGroup: MenuGroup) => {
      formArray.push(this.buildSubFormGroup(menuGroup))
    });

  }

  private buildSubFormGroup(menuGroup: MenuGroup): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      title: [menuGroup.title, Validators.required],
      items: this.buildMenuItemFormGroup(menuGroup.menuItems)
    });
  }

  private buildMenuItemFormGroup(menuItems: MenuItem[]): FormArray {
    const formArray = this.fb.array([]);
    const formGroup = this.fb.group({});
    menuItems.forEach((menuItem: MenuItem) => {
      formGroup.addControl(menuItem.title, new FormControl());
    });
    formArray.push(formGroup);
    return formArray;
  }
```

And go [this](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/) article to get a clear idea. And Use this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-test) to see how to create form groups and formArrays.

Comment: Great. Thanks. But what if the Role Data is dynamically fetched? I mean the number of MenuGroups and MenuItems might change. Hence. How do I deal with it?

Comment: That does not matter. The forms in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-test) that I've created is dynamically generated. If you want to test add some more elements to it and try.